# How to change size of igc-star component in angular

Tags: angular

How to change size of igc-star component from igniteui-webcomponents package in angular?
https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/rating
I tried to change fontsize in css but it did not change size, I only managed to change color with:

```
.rating-stars {
    color: goldenrod;
    
}
```

Html code looks like:

```
 <igc-rating class="rating-stars" value={{property.rating}} min="0" max="5"></igc-rating>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, so unable to provide you a concrete solution. Would be great if you can provide your `igc-rating`component, is it a built-in component provided by which library, or is this component built by your own (if yes, share the source code).

Comment: It is from igniteui-webcomponents package.

Comment: you are probably running into view encapsulation.  By default, Angular doesn't let you effect the css of elements inside of a child component from the parent level.  You can try using the deprecated `::ng-deep` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Styling documentation](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-web-components/web-components/components/inputs/rating#styling), you should define the CSS styling rule with `--symbol-size` attribute to adjust the size accordingly.

```
igc-rating {
    --symbol-size: 44px;  /* Desired size */
}
```